# How to use postgres function string_agg() in yii2 ActiveDataProvider?

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2, aggregate-functions

I have tried the following in model.

```
$query = Students::find()->select("string_agg(distinct name,'|') ");
```

When I use like this I got Error:

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"
>   LINE 1: SELECT string_agg(distinct name, "'|')" FROM "students..^The
>   SQL being executed was: SELECT string_agg(distinct name, "'|')"   FROM
>   "students" LIMIT 20

I tried the same with the escaping character also , that time also it shows the same error . How do I use this in **yii2** ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
Students::find()->select(["string_agg(distinct name,'|')"])->column()
```

Comment: How to use multiple columns like this

Comment: you're already agregating name column, what other columns are you expecting to see in a grouped query result, this not seems to be possible.

Comment: You'll get all distinct names with this query, so I gave an answer to your question anyway